# Get a different result when calling the same function

Tags: scala

I am a scala newbie.

This is my code. The results of two types of same method use are different, 
can anyone explain to me why???

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the terminal output into the text of your question rather than using a screenshot--it makes it more difficult for potential answerers to help you.

Comment: Methods ending with a colon used in infix notation are right associative in scala, so `lxx1 :: lxx2` is equivalent to `lxx2.::(lxx1)`. You're getting different results because you run different operations.

Comment: @alextsc But isn't :: a method name here???

Comment: Yes. `::` is a method name. Method names ending with a colon are right associative. Thats what Im saying. :)

Comment: OK, I get it, thks

Comment: And whoever was the great soul who flagged this question as off-topic needs to rethink what is on-topic on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that in Scala, all `functions` ( or "operators") which have names ending with a `colon ':'` are deemed as `right associative` when used with infix notation.

So... for your function,

```
def ::(t: TG) = ???
```

When, you are writing

```
val lxx3 = lxx1 :: lxx2
```

The function `::` associates to the right (ie. with `lxx2`). So it is actually equivalent to

```
val lxx3 = lxx2.::(lxx1)
```

instead of this,

```
val lxx3 = lxx1.::(lxx2)
```

Comment: To be more precise, methods ending with a colon form an expression that is right associative and are additionaly invoked on the right operand (these are two different things).